# Dev server and local code different even though they are on the same commit

Tags: git, github, deployment

So I was testing out `git revert` and `git reset` to test how to rollback changes after deploying to server. I made a small change adding the text "test" to a view, added, commited, and deployed.

This puts us at commit 2, which has the "test" text and it appears in the dev server as expected. Locally, I ran git reset --hard to the previous commit, commit 1 which doesn't have "test" on the view. I then pushed the code back up with -f in order to force the reset.

However, when I view the dev server, it still says "test" on the view.

To add, it seems now whenever I modify that view file there will be a merge conflict that I can't fix because my local says there is no merge conflict.

Comment: Are you pushing to a repository *with* a working directory?

Comment: Yes it is a working directory

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the server you are deploying to and doing a git pull from has any changes. Is it possible there are changes on the remote and you aren't seeing the git message of merge conflicts or overwriting changes?

Comment: So when I SSH into that instance, I see the "test" code there, but even after pulling the code, it does not appear in my local

Comment: do a git status on the remote, you might have to do a git pull, git commit -m, git push, etc

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by SSH into the instance and making changes directly but to no avail. After I pulled the code, committed again and pushed and it worked for some reason.

Thanks everybody!